# Quickblox getting a session receives "Unexpected signature" error

Tags: python, session, quickblox

When getting a session, I get an "unexpected error".

Here is my code to get the signature (modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541616/invalid-signature-error-when-sending-an-authorization-request-to-quickblox-via-p/17542012#17542012) since that code is without some imports and notably hmac.new() is used instead of hmac() since that code doesn't work for me.

```
import sys
import json
import time
import random
import hashlib
import hmac
import urllib
import httplib

application_id = '3427'
auth_key = 'PLYHedAmxwdvt59'
auth_secret = '*some secret key*'


nonce = str(random.randint(1, 10000))
timestamp = str(int(time.time()))

signature_raw_body = ("application_id=" + application_id + "&auth_key=" + auth_key +
            "&nonce=" + nonce + "&timestamp=" + timestamp)

signature = hmac.new(auth_secret, signature_raw_body, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()

params = urllib.urlencode({'application_id': application_id,
                           'auth_key': auth_key,
                           'timestamp': timestamp, 'nonce' : nonce,
                           'signature' : signature})

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.quickblox.com")
conn.request("POST", "/session", params, {})
response = conn.getresponse()

print response.read()
print "signature = '%s'" % signature
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session>
  <application-id type="integer">3427</application-id>
  <created-at type="datetime">2013-08-04T12:19:10Z</created-at>
  <device-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
  <id type="integer">3552056</id>
  <nonce type="integer">5855</nonce>
  <token>686840081c18c7dd0e0a779c233e0d9605bcb567</token>
  <ts type="integer">1375618748</ts>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2013-08-04T12:19:10Z</updated-at>
  <user-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
</session>

signature = 'f08b68b645184619bbe59bac217506e66a840425'
```

Next I use curl to attempt to create a session:

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H
>   "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0" -d
>   '{"application_id":"3427","auth_key":"PLYHedAmxwdvt59","nonce":"33432","timestamp":"1375619372","signature":"f08b68b645184619bbe59bac217506e66a840425"}'
>   http://api.quickblox.com/session.json

I get this as a result:
{"errors":{"base":["Unexpected signature"]}}

Something went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0" -d '{"application_id":"92","auth_key":"wJHdOcQSxXQGWx5","nonce":"315","timestamp":"1375624737","signature":"f36336b8bc8449b8252edbc0ee441cdb5856112c"}' http://api.quickblox.com/session.json
```

Result:

```
{"session":{"application_id":92,"created_at":"2013-08-04T13:59:50Z","device_id":null,"id":3553701,"nonce":315,"token":"1d423b6633e2fc82f81d88b65f3e26198853c84c","ts":1375624737,"updated_at":"2013-08-04T13:59:50Z","user_id":null}}
```

You should check code which generates your signature

Comment: If I get the token back, doesn't that mean the signature was generated correctly? Previously the server would tell me something wrong with the signature (I forgot the exact wording).

Comment: I see that you Python code which generates signature is not equal to code in link

Comment: Because the code in link doesn't run. It's missing some imports, and when it is imported, that hmac() Alex had simply doesn't work. But, I'll take a hard look again.

Comment: I've just doubled checked. Well, other than hmac.new() instead of hmac()(which doesn't run, it will complain `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`) and hashlib.sha1 instead of just sha1. (that's just the matter of `import hashlib` or `from haslib import sha1`, I presume, since Alex's code doesn't include the necessary import statements), I don't see any real difference.

Comment: Still wondering what's causing the problem. I tried the iOS sdk custom object example and it works like a charm as far as the session creation goes. I don't have access to the SDK (obviously) but the iOS code appears to make just one session request. I'll try some more.

Comment: OK it turns out I'm calling session.json twice without realizing it. I just need that one call.

BTW what's /auth for?

Comment: /auth - this is old & deprecated endpoint, you should use /session

Comment: Hey! I am facing similar problem. At times it works and at times it throws -{"errors":{"base":["Unexpected signature"]}}.  Has anyone faced that ?